# CSS: why doesn't the right element get selected?

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/oscholz/pen/qNYPVL

I am trying to select only the Random unattached paragraph.

I've tried a number of things that I think should all work (see below or the

```css
p:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
.a:not(.relevant) {
  color: red;
}
.a:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
.a:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h2 class="important">Hi again</h2>
<p class="a">Random unattached paragraph</p>
<div class="relevant">
  <p class="a">first</p>
  <p class="a">second</p>
  <p>third</p>
  <p>fourth</p>
  <p class="a">fifth</p>
  <p class="a">sixth</p>
  <p>seventh</p>
</div>
```

None of them do. What am I missing?
I know I could change the HTML, but I don't want to do that. :)

Comment: Can you add it a class or it's impossible?

Comment: What actually distinguishes that paragraph from the others? Is it just that it's not inside `.relevant`? You could simply write a rule for `p.a` and then override that rule for `.relevant p.a`

Comment: Define "unattached." If you are looking for just the one that is a direct child of body - `body > p [ ... }`

Comment: For current HTML, the rule you are looking for is `.important + .a`, which means .a immediately after .important, but yeah - try to add more meaning to your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. You need to decide the *semantic meaning* of what you want to select and devise your selector based on that.

- **`body > p.a`** would select all `p.a` elements that are direct children of the body tag (i.e., not nested inside any containers).
- **`.important + p.a`** would select any `p.a` elements that come immediately after an `.important` element.
- **`p.a:nth-of-type(1)`** would select the first paragraph tag if it has class `a`.
- **`p.a`** would select all `p.a` elements, and you could then use `.relevant p.a` to override (or undo) any attributes on the ones you didn't want to affect.

Well-written semantic HTML should always describe the *purpose* of an element based on context, tag choice, and class and/or id attributes. If your document's markup is not semantic, there is only so much you can do to create a generalized CSS selector for the components you want to affect.

Comment: body > p.a {
  color: red;
}

Comment: that does it with a single rule. That's great! Thank you Woodrow!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is `body > p`

This is a test question in a Purewal's "Learning Web App Development":

https://books.google.com/books?id=JLDZAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%E2%80%9CSelect+only+the+random,+unattached+paragraph.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=2h8FEOEPar&sig=tIdTEyLid_qpzEJPmYYTIIVxM50&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqnLG588_OAhWBrB4KHYUJByYQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CSelect%20only%20the%20random%2C%20unattached%20paragraph.%E2%80%9D&f=false

The book author points us to the answer in his next paragraph, here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors#relselectors

Purewal is illustrating the difference between CSS's descendant and child selectors, which is why, using the HTML defined for the question (see below), the simplest answer that illustrates the lesson is pedagogically correct.

```
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h2 class="important">Hi again</h2>
<p class="a">Random unattached paragraph</p>
<div class="relevant">
  <p class="a">first</p>
  <p class="a">second</p>
  <p>third</p>
  <p>fourth</p>
  <p class="a">fifth</p>
  <p class="a">sixth</p>
  <p>seventh</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Excerpt From: Semmy Purewal. “Learning Web Application Development.”

Answer (score 0):

```
body > .a { color: red; }
```

This would select only the `.a` outside the `.relevant` container.  You could also do something like this:

```
.a { color: red; }
.relevant .a { color: black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create the default rules in .relevant for all it's children. Then let the rules for .a handle those particular children. No hoops, nth or piping.
Your unattached <p>'s will end up with a different style than the ones with the .a class.

Answer (score -1):

Try...

```
body > p{
    color: red;  
}
```